# Win32 api programming - wm_paint after resizing

Tags: winapi

I want to redraw window on every window resize, but I dont want to call WM_PAINT until resizing is finished. I tried it using WM_EXITSIZEMOVE message, but I unsuccessfully. Is there any way to, for example paint TextOut on every resize (on every mouse up after resizing)?

Thanks

Comment: How would Windows know what to paint in the exposed areas of your window while resizing is taking place?

Comment: It does take WM_ENTER/EXITSIZEMOVE.  Clearly your question is too poorly documented to answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you receive `WM_EXITSIZEMOVE`, simply `Invalidate()` the window and let Windows generate a new `WM_PAINT` message on its own scheduling.

Comment: But it is painting all the time during the resize (because of message WM_PAINT). I have to change invalid region color after every resize of window (not during resize). I want to make this:

[link](http://imageshack.us/scaled/landing/824/screenshot20121026at808.png)

numbers say about how much resizes were during the run time, and which part is first, which second and so on...

Comment: Create an in-memory bitmap that is the same size as the window, then every time the window is resized, resize the bitmap to match and fill in any new area with the current chosen color. Whenever you receive `WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE`, choose a new color. Then each time a `WM_PAINT` is received, simply draw the current bitmap as-is onto the window.

Comment: But I can not repaint window only on WM_EXITSIZEMOVE and WM_PAINT is being received during window resizing, not on mouse up. And I get this: [link](http://zaslike.com/files/565g6srih0yfv6atkol.png)

Comment: Then you are likely not managing the drawing of the bitmap in the messages correctly. I'll provide a small demo when I have some more time.